# IS NULL with symfony2 and doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I'm trying this piece of code but I keep bumping into an error

```
$q = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder('p')
    ->select('p')
    ->from('ClendarRecipeBundle:RecipePlan', 'p')
    ->leftJoin('p.recipeCalendars', 'c')
    ->groupBy('c.recipePlan')
    ->having('p.portions > SUM(c.portions)')
    ->orHaving('SUM(c.portions) IS NULL')
    ->getQuery();
```

when SUM(c.portions) is NULL the first having doesn't select it, so I tried to add orHaving but symfony2 gives me the following error:

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 204: Error: Expected =, <, <=, <>, >, >=, !=, got 'IS'
```

I tried a few different ways to write, any of you have a good suggestion what I could try?
I could try RAWS Sql but I prefer the code in the QueryBuilder with objects as a result.

Comment: Replace `IS NULL` with `= NULL`

Comment: if I do that I get the following error which is normal since as far as you know you can compare NULL like that. (at least not in sql)

    [Syntax Error] line 0, col 206: Error: Expected Literal, got 'NULL'

Comment: My bad, make it `SUM(c.portions) != 0`.

Comment: that's great and a logical solution, one I should have seen myself. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should have been:

```
SUM(c.portions) != 0
```